# Detecting start and end of WFS layer loading in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, javascript, wfs, vector-layer, loading

I have a WFS layer that takes a while to load.

I would like to show a 'load', while it loads, so it doesn't get the impression that nothing is happening.

Any idea?

```
    var my_layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: ' My Layer',
    visible: false,
    source:  new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
        return urlGeoserver + 'wfs?service=WFS&' +
        'version='+versionGeoserver+'&request=GetFeature&typename=geo: MY_LAYER&' +
            'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
            'all=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the docs of `ol.source.Vector` at https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html, you'll se there are `featuresloadstart` and `featuresloadend` events that can be used to detect layer loading start and end times.

This part of the code could then look something like this:

```
my_layer.getSource().on('featuresloadstart', function(evt) {
  console.log('start');
});
my_layer.getSource().on('featuresloadend', function(evt) {
  console.log('end');
});
```

**EDIT**: This works for OL 6, OL 5 does not have these events for vector source.

Comment: thanks. I added the events as per your answer but it didn't work.

Comment: See working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/kwr7god4/. Since GeoJSON us very big it uses `ol.loadingstrategy.bbox`, but I tested it also with `ol.loadingstrategy.all` and it worked also.

Comment: Thanks, I identified your code, copied the events and the alert to show, still it didn't work. Does it have to do with the openlayers version?

Comment: Then there is something wrong in your code. If you can, put relevant part of your code on JSFiddle.

Comment: I managed to solve it, I'll post the resolution I found. Thanks

Comment: Please don't post solution as a part of answer, rather post it as an answer to your own question. And by the way, which version of OL are you using?

Comment: OL Version v5.3.0

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for for OpenLayers v5.3.0:

JS

```
my_layer.on("precompose", function () {
    document.getElementById("my_loader").classList.add("loader");
});         

my_layer.on("render", function () {
    document.getElementById("my_loader").classList.remove("loader");            
});
```

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/loader.css">
<div id="my_loader"></div>
```

CSS

```
.loader {
content: "";
border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
border-radius: 50%;
border-top: 16px solid #003a14;
border-bottom: 16px solid #003a14;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```